# how to join specific column of dataframe with another in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scale

I have four dataframes,

df1 as,

```
 name         city
--------------------------------
 kum        chennai
kamesh     bangalore
```

df2 as,

```
name   street
-------------------------------
kum     2nd str
kamesh  10th str
```

I need to add name with city and street.
output dataframe as,such as,
df3 =

```
name     street    city
-----------------------------
kum       2nd str    Chennai
kamesh    10th str   bangalore.
```

how can I convert as df3 using Scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

join them as following

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("name"))
```

by default its a *inner join*, you can define the `join` type as

```
val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("name"), "inner")
```

You should have output as

```
+------+---------+--------+
|name  |city     |street  |
+------+---------+--------+
|kum   |chennai  |2nd str |
|kamesh|bangalore|10th str|
+------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the this:

1. `val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("name").equalTo(df2("name")))` but it will show the join key twice
2. `val df4 = df1.join(df2, Seq("name"), "inner")` this will only show the join key once
   the code like this below: 
   enter code here

`import spark.implicits._
    val df1: DataFrame = Seq(("kum","chennai"),("kamesh","bangalore")).toDF("name","city")
    val df2: DataFrame = Seq(("kum","2nd str"),("kamesh","10th str")).toDF("name","street")
    val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("name").equalTo(df2("name")))
    df3.show()
    val df4 = df1.join(df2, Seq("name"), "inner")
    df4.show()`

the result :

```
+------+---------+------+--------+
|  name|     city|  name|  street|
+------+---------+------+--------+
|   kum|  chennai|   kum| 2nd str|
|kamesh|bangalore|kamesh|10th str|
+------+---------+------+--------+
+------+---------+--------+
|  name|     city|  street|
+------+---------+--------+
|   kum|  chennai| 2nd str|
|kamesh|bangalore|10th str|
+------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: hi,if I have different columns in dataframe 2 such as val df2: DataFrame = Seq(("Object1","OBJECT_TYPE1"),("OBJECT2","OBJECT_TYPE2")).toDF("OBJECT","TYPE"), and want to add to df1, results shows empty rows. how to join this.